# How to filter columns returned under ListItemAllField in REST API

Tags: rest, filter, expand, office365-restapi, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I used below rest API which I can get all items in specific folder inside SharePoint document library
    /_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('serverrelativefolderurl')/files?    $expand=ListItemAllFields

I would need to filter some columns which I get under ListItemAllField , I used
    "_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('serverrelativefolder‌​url')/files?$expand=‌​ListItemAllField$fil‌​ter=ACT eq '23'

"ACT" is columns name which has returned under ListItemAllField , but I get Error message "Field or property \"ACT\" does not exist." , is there any way to filter columns returned under ListItemAllField

Thanks ,
Laleh

Answer (score 0):

Solution1: Instead of $ use & and try

Solution2: Check the internal name for ACT, if it varies then using internal name and check.